# Integral $\int e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x) + \csc(x)\cot(x))dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> How to find integral $\int e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x) +
>  \csc(x)\cot(x))dx$ ?

I tried using the formula  $\int e^{g(x)}(f(x)g'(x)+ f'(x))dx=e^{g(x)}f(x)$ but that is not working.Help!

Comment: looks like this one is doomed

Comment: @tired It seems I am doomed too.Could solve only 1 out of the 10 integrals i was supposed to have solved today :-P!

Comment: Just passed by and hope this would be informative: Matlab shows that the result is $$(\exp (\cos x)) \cdot (\sin x) \cdot (x\sin x + 1)/[(\cos x)^{2} - 1] + \text{constant}.$$

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, then I apologise for my assumptions, but it still doesn't mean that you will get *anything* out of integrals which were *solved for you by others*. It is not a 'self-study' if you just read the solutions made by other people

Comment: I solved 35 out of the 40 questions myself.Only 5 questions I asked.I agree I wrote it in short.I will edit it at night after all my tasks are over.Hope you don't mind :) @You'reInMyEye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x) +
 \csc(x)\cot(x)) \\ =  e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x) -1 + 1+
 \csc(x)\cot(x)) \\ = e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x) - 1 + \sin(x) \csc(x)+
 \csc(x)\cot(x)) \\= e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x) - 1) +  e^{\cos (x)}(\sin(x) \csc(x)+
 \csc(x)\cot(x))$

Caution: sign of the derivative of $\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x)+\csc(x)\cot(x))dx=\int e^{\cos (x)}x \sin (x)dx+\int e^{\cos (x)}\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^{2}x}dx$$

Now notice that $$\int e^{\cos (x)}\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^{2}}dx=\int e^{\cos (x)}d(-\frac{1}{\sin{x}})=-\frac{e^{\cos{x}}}{\sin{x}}-\int e^{\cos (x)}dx,$$
where we used partial integration.

Therefore, $$I=-\frac{e^{\cos{x}}}{\sin{x}}+\int e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x)-1)dx.$$
Since $$d(x e^{\cos{x}})=e^{\cos{x}}-x\sin{x}e^{\cos{x}}$$ and
$$\int e^{\cos (x)}(x \sin (x)-1)dx=-\int d(x e^{\cos{x}})=-x e^{\cos{x}}+C,$$
we finally have $$I=-\frac{e^{\cos{x}}}{\sin{x}}-xe^{\cos{x}}+C.$$